# JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find myapp.server.layer3persistence.UserData with id xxx

Tags: spring-boot

I need your help because I do not understand what is happening: I have an exception thrown by a code that should never generate this specific exception. I'm using Spring Boot v2.2.7.RELEASE

The exception is:

```
SERVER ERROR: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find myapp.server.layer3persistence.UserData with id 4673fa77-c8f2-45ac-886d-b5a8433044d6; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find myapp.server.layer3persistence.UserData with id 4673fa77-c8f2-45ac-886d-b5a8433044d6] with root cause
```

The stack trace is:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find myapp.server.layer3persistence.UserData with id 9d8b7a7d-fd34-45d2-8a6a-68aee6ae1dd1
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1184)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1049)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:697)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad$EntityResolver.lambda$static$0(TwoPhaseLoad.java:657)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntityEntryLoadedState(TwoPhaseLoad.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1203)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1004)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:962)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2857)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2839)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2671)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2666)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1412)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1581)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.findByProfileId(Unknown Source)
    at myapp.server.layer2services.UserServices.addProfile(UserServices.java:332)
    at myapp.server.layer1controllers.UserController.addSingleProfile(UserController.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The interesting lines are:

```
    at myapp.server.layer2services.UserServices.addProfile(UserServices.java:332)
    at myapp.server.layer1controllers.UserController.addSingleProfile(UserController.java:68)
```

Let's try to look at the offending lines:

UserController:66-69

```
    @PostMapping("/addSingleProfile")
    public void addSingleProfile(@RequestHeader String authToken, @RequestHeader String deviceId, @RequestBody String json) throws IOException {
        userServices.addProfile(authToken, deviceId, json, true);
    }
```

UserServices.java:326-346

```
public void addProfile(String authToken, String deviceId, String json, boolean isSingleProfile) throws IOException {
        UserData userData = findUserByAuthTokenOrRequestLogout(authToken, deviceId);
        UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile(userData, new Gson().fromJson(json, UserProfileDAO.class));

        // is it a new userProfile or an existing one to be updated?
        if (userProfileRepository.existsByProfileId(userProfile.getProfileId())) {
            UserProfile existingProfile = userProfileRepository.findByProfileId(userProfile.getProfileId()).get();
            // the profile exists, so we update it
            userProfile.setId(existingProfile.getId());
        };

        if (isSingleProfile) {
            userData.getSingleProfiles().add(userProfile);
        } else {
            userData.getOrganizationProfiles().add(userProfile);
        }

        userProfileRepository.save(userProfile);

        userDataRepository.save(userData);
    }
```

The line UserServices.java:332 (indicated in the stack trace) is:

```
UserProfile existingProfile = userProfileRepository.findByProfileId(userProfile.getProfileId()).get();
```

but this line cannot throw the given exception because it's inside the if clause:

```
        if (userProfileRepository.existsByProfileId(userProfile.getProfileId())) {
            UserProfile existingProfile = userProfileRepository.findByProfileId(userProfile.getProfileId()).get();
            // the profile exists, so we update it
            userProfile.setId(existingProfile.getId());
        };
```

The UserProfileRepository is implemented so:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface UserProfileRepository extends CrudRepository<UserProfile, String> {

    public Optional<UserProfile> findByProfileId(String profileId);
    public Optional<UserProfile> findByName(String name);
    public Optional<UserProfile> findByNameIgnoreCase(String name);
    public Optional<UserProfile> findByNameAndGroupKey(String name, String groupKey);

    public boolean existsByProfileId(String profileId);
}
```

The same expection is produced by this equivalent code:

```
userProfileRepository.findByProfileId(userProfile.getProfileId()).ifPresent((UserProfile existingProfile) -> {
            // the profile exists, so we update it
            userProfile.setId(existingProfile.getId());
        });
```

Comment: Hi @Francesco Galgani i think like problem in database table user with 4673fa77-c8f2-45ac-886d-b5a8433044d6] join or some thing not good in database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar issue in my case was fixed by updating `@ManyToOne` annotation:

```
@NotNull
@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

added: `nullable = false`, `optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY` plus - `@NotNull` (*javax.validation.constraints.NotNull*)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response. It's actually been many months, and I can't remember how I solved the problem (and if I solved it). I accept your answer, but since it's been a long time I don't have the possibility to verify it. I only remember that I solved various weird issues by adding to application.properties the line: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true`